# Using JavaScript, is it possible to see the URL or header info of a redirect from a PHP page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe and it loads a page, random.php, which immediatly redirects to another page.

```
header('Location: /random_page');
```

This page is not on the same domain as the parent of the iframe. **Is there a way using JavaScript to see the URL of the redirect or the header information or is it impossible due to security?**

This is what I have tried so far but the value is always random.php. This is called after the iframe finishes loading.

```
var source = $("iframe").attr('src');
```

Comment: well, the iframe attribute doesn't change with a server redirection - the only way I can think of achieving this is if the random pages and your main page use [PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate with each other `window.postMessage method safely enables cross-origin communication` - safely being the key

Comment: @JaromandaX This is a very helpful bit of information. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: It is not possible. You can use three different methods to get URL content:

1. Request page as a resource
2. Send `XMLHttpRequest`
3. Use iframe

None of these three methods allow you to distinguish between 200 (OK) and 302 (MOVED) response codes. If page writes redirection header, browser engine immediatelly jumps to that page.